# Signature to prove of ownership of arbitrary sized data

Tags: public-key, signature, ed25519

I am familiar with public key signatures, but I was wondering if there is a method to accomplish the following.

Suppose I publish a file (say a PDF article) on a peer to peer network. How can I generate some sort of public key or signature which will allow one peer to prove to another peer that they have a copy of this file? Something like a signature that treats the full data as a private key, and for which I can put the public key on e.g. my website.

The best method I can come up with is using a hash of the file as the private key in a standard signature scheme. However this is suboptimal because a peer might not actually have a copy of the file anyore, it might just have stored the hash but deleted the file itself.

I am looking for a method that I can wrap up in some challenge-response scheme that allows a peer to prove that they have access to a full copy of the file that belongs to a particular public key.

Comment: @the_one_who_voted_down: please comment and give a statement why you voted down.

Comment: Just sending a random challenge and performing a hash over the challenge and file should do the trick I think. The hash should however be over a structure that includes the file size to avoid length extension attacks. Note that you would need additional protection against man-in-the-middle (e.g. by using a signature with a private key of the peer). It would also be easy to collude with somebody that holds the document; I don't think that can be avoided.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? How should the requester verify that `H(challenge + file)` is correct from the public key? The requester does not have the file. I'm not worried about mitm.

Comment: Just a general signature verification. If you send a random challenge then the hash in the signature over challenge and file should be unique. You can obviously verify it if you have the same file and challenge. Obviously the challenge should be at least be 128 bits in size. Note that the challenge must be first, otherwise the intermediate result may be stored. If unsure, use a HMAC with challenge as key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : $\:$ "You can obviously verify it if you have the same file and challenge", but it's far from obvious how the requester can verify it if "The requester does not have the file." $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Yeah, not explicitly asked for , but for a P2P network that might be a given... Maybe the other peers can send a challenge + hash upon request...

Comment: Ask the client to append a random (chosen by you) value to the file. Then ask it to send you the hash of that combination. Calculate it yourself and check if the hashes match.

Comment: This does not work for Merkle-Damgard hash functions.  The peer can compute a partial hash of the file, up to the last block.  Using this partial hash (and the last few bytes of the file if needed), the peer can produce responses to challenges without needing the entire file.

Comment: Didn't think about that... Would inserting data in each block help?

Comment: This reminds me to [Proofs of Storage (PoS)](https://cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/pdp.pdf): "_Proofs of storage (PoS) are interactive protocols allowing a client to verify that a server faithfully
stores a file_"

Comment: @cygnusv mind elaborating with an example or some code to illustrate this technique to a non-cryptographer?

Comment: @TimMcLean Obviously, _appending_ doesn't work, but _prepending_ does. More accurately, the challenge consists of sending a salt, and getting a hash of the file with that salt. The problem with this approach is that it's too expensive to compute hash of the whole file every time, so PoS should involve some kind of Merkle tree to recompute only a logarithmic amount of hashes on every challenge.

Answer (score 4):

**Proofs of Storage** (PoS) are challenge-response protocols that allow a client to verify that a server is truthfully storing a file. See [this paper from Ateniese, Kamara and Katz](https://cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/pdp.pdf) for an example of PoS.

The basic idea is explained in this quote from that paper:

> Viewing the file $\vec f$ as an $n$-dimensional vector, the client
>   begins by tagging each element of $\vec f$ and then sending both $\vec f$ and the vector of tags $\vec t$ to the server. To verify that the
>   server is storing the entire file, the client sends a random challenge
>   vector $\vec c$ and  the server returns $\mu =\sum_i c_i f_i$ along
>   with a tag $\tau$, computed using $\vec f$,$\vec t$, and $\vec c$,
>   which is supposed to authenticate this value.

The key aspect here is defining

1. how the client (or more correctly, the one who uploads the file) create tags $\vec t$,
2. how the server computes response tag $\tau$,
3. (and perhaps more importantly), how the server's response can be verified publicly.

I don't have time at the moment to explain the details of these aspects (they are a little bit complicated...I will try to do it later). In any case, it is important to remark that in order to verify a response in the proposal of Ateniese, Kamara and Katz, one does not need the original file. This is a public-key setting, and the private key is only used for tagging the file at the beginning. After that, everything is done using the public key (both the proof of storage and its verification).

There are similar proposals, such as Proofs of Retrievability (PoR) and Provable Data Possession (PDP).

Comment: Tried to read the paper but it is unclear to me if can actually be implemented or is merely theoretical proof based on (impractical) homomorphic methods.